# Log transformation to Likert scale measures

Tags: regression, data-transformation, likert

If this has been answered elsewhere, or if questions like these are not appropriate here, then apologies in advance.

Conducting some exploratory analysis for a survey study, where the aim is to predict anxiety severity using a set of predictor variables. The outcome variable for Anxiety is the GAD-7: a 7 item questionnaire scored on a Likert scale of 0 to 3 (0 = "Not at all" and 3 = "Nearly every day"). From here a total score is generated by adding the response for all 7 items, and the score ranges from 0 to 21.

A histogram of the variable shows a large positive skew (as expected/hoped as the majority of participants have a low to mild severity of anxiety), however I this skew means that running a linear regression would not be appropriate. Especially a test of skewness on my model shows that the assumption is violated.

I have two questions relating to this problem:

1. Is a log transformation appropriate for running a linear regression analysis for this variable?
2. If the log transformation is appropriate, an additional transformation needs to be applied to GAD-7 due to the 0 scores recorded (for those with very low levels of anxiety), so that a log transformation is possible. For this scenario, is it better practice to add a small number to the measure so that a log transformation is possible? (like 0.0001?) Or is it better to add a number that is associated with Likert scoring system? (In this instance 7, due to the 7 items of the scale and the 1 point interval in the Likert scoring - effectively changing the scoring from 0-3 to 1-4).

Many thanks to any responses.

Comment: Your data is not numeric, so you shouldn't really be using regular regression no matter what the transformation is. You want to be using some type of ordinal regression, like a cumulative link model.

Comment: It's not necessarily true that "this skew means that running a linear regression would not be appropriate." If the predictors in your model also have corresponding skew, it's quite possible that the _residuals_ of observations around model predictions would be well behaved. That's what's important for regression, although with so few levels it might not be wise to use ordinary least-squares regression here. You could consider ordinal regression, that models the rankings of outcomes.

Comment: You can look here for a tutorial on the type of ordinal model that I mentioned: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clmm2_tutorial.pdf